# What are the dice for in Angry Birds?

Tags: angry-birds

I've noticed dice in some Angry Birds levels like the ones in the image below:

[image]

Do they have any significance?  Are they related to the golden eggs by any chance?

Comment: If you watch them closely, the number of dots on the dice decreases each time they're in a collision

Comment: Why did you accept a worse answer?

Comment: @DVK the accepted answer was out for over a year before the one with more upvotes.

Comment: @ShadowZ. - and the user has been active on the site until well into 2014. Your point? The acceptance mark can be changed at anytime

Comment: @DVK he probably did not care to check back on/change it (or would feel bad for reducing the one guys rep).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just some (pretty) flotsam - they don't play any part other than being an obstacle.

(You'll find lots more of such things in later levels - only items like the crates of dynamite and balloons are "active".)

Comment: And no, they are not related to the golden eggs in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 30):

The dice decrease by one each time they hit another object but are not destroyed. When they are destroyed, you earn 1000 times the number on the die. So the trick is to try and destroy them on the first hit, in order to earn 6000 points.

Comment: Wow, that will be key to achieving 3 stars on some levels. Good find!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that they are worth some points when destroyed.

Comment: Isn't everything?

Comment: Yup.  I think so.

Answer (score 0):

The more the number on them is hit the more the impact

Answer (score -3):

The dice is mostly like any other obstacle, but it shows more significantly that it is damaged and the hits left before destruction.

Comment: You are saying what has been said 7 years ago.